# Symfony Doctrine Autoload from relation Many-to-One/One-to-Many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 Main entities and one relation table in my Symfony/Doctrine App.
My goal is to load them Easily.

I have Gallery class that looks like this:

```php
class Gallery
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=GalleryHasImage::class, mappedBy="gallery")
     */
    private $hasImages;**strong text**
```

Image class:

```php
class Image implements ImageInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;
```

and Relation table with extra data:

```php
class GalleryHasImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Gallery
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gallery\Gallery", inversedBy="hasImages")
     */
    private $gallery;

    /**
     * @var Image
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image\Image", inversedBy="hasGalleries")
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="timestamp", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private int $position;
```

My goal is to have simple getter in my Gallery Class to get images without position. Something like

```php
/**
     * @Route("/gallery/{id}/images", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id":"\d+"})
     * @param Gallery $gallery)
     * @return Response
     */
public function getImages(Gallery $gallery)
{
   print_r($gallery->getImages());
}
```

Right now I am only able to do it with extra steps like:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/gallery/{id}/images", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 * @param Gallery $gallery)
 * @return Response
 */
public function getImages(Gallery $gallery)
{
    foreach($gallery->getHasImages as $hasImage)
    { 
        print_r($hasImage->getImage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by mapping your `hasImages` element to `getImage()` returned object either on the controller or in a getter in your gallery entity

### Gallery Entity

```php
class Gallery
{
    /** ... */
    
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return array_map(function ($hasImages) {
            return $hasImages->getImage();
        },$this->getHasImages());
    }
}
```

and then you can use like:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/gallery/{id}/images", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 * @param Gallery $gallery)
 * @return Response
 */
public function getImages(Gallery $gallery)
{
    print_r($gallery->getImages());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to loop though the `hasImages` collection and call `getImage()` on each filling an array, then return the array.

So, in your `Gallery` you could have a method like this:

```php
        public function getImages(){
            $images = [];
            foreach($this->hasImages as $hasImage){
                $images[] = $hasImage->getImage();
            }

            return $images;
        }
```